# How can I detect the browser in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to detect the browser with JavaScript.

I have an image gallery with different js files for FireFox, Chrome, and IE. How can I detect the browser display the corresponding file?

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using jquery you can use [their API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) to detect the browser. Otherwise you can extract the users browser from the `navigator.useragent` property.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) in the HTML to grab entirely different script files:

```
<!--[if IE]> 
<script src="http://example.com/ie-specific.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<script src="http://example.com/real-browsers.js"></script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```